# Creating modes for the following Program

Tags: python

At my sailing club we have a race timer that runs of Python (Raspberry Pie) As i can Program some Python i have been asked to reprogram it to include different modes when the "Lap" button is pressed before the start button. Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pygame as pg
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time, math

pg.init()

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(12,GPIO.IN)
GPIO.setup(13,GPIO.IN)
GPIO.setup(16,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(18,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(22,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(7,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.output(16,False)
GPIO.output(18,False)
GPIO.output(22,False)
GPIO.output(7,False)
lap_time = []

hooter_out = 7
red_out = 22
amber_out = 18
green_out = 16

white = (255,255,255)
yellow = (255,255,0)
black = (0,0,0)
race_count = -301
next_tick = 0
hooter_blast = False
hooter_length = 2

screen = pg .display.set_mode((640,400))
pg.display.set_caption("Text adventures with pygame")
myfont = pg.font.SysFont("Comic Sans MS",80)
pg.mouse.set_visible(False)

screen.fill(white)

loop = 0

label = myfont.render("Race Time        -300",1,black)
screen.blit(label, (0,20))
pg.display.flip()
#   loop = loop + 1

start_time = time.time()

running = True
race_started = False


while running:
    tick = 0
    next_tick = 0
    screen.fill(white)
    label = myfont.render("Race Time        -300",1,black)
    screen.blit(label, (0,20))
    pg.display.flip()

    race_count = -301
    lap_time=[]
    while tick < 20:
        lap_time.append("")
        tick = tick + 1     
    last_string = ""
    start_time = time.time()

    while GPIO.input(12)==False:
        current_time = time.time()

        count_time = time.time() - start_time
        if count_time >= next_tick:
            next_tick=next_tick+1
            race_count=race_count+1

        elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time - 300
        #if elapsed_time >= 0:
        #   race_started = True 

        #screen_time = elapsed_time #**2
        #screen_time = screen_time**0.5
#       if elapsed_time <= 0:
#           screen_time = math.floor(screen_time)
#       else:
#           screen_time = math.ceil(screen_time)

        screen.fill(white)

        count_str = '{0: >12}'.format(race_count)


        first_line = "Race Time" + count_str #   {:7.0f}".format(race_count)

        label = myfont.render(first_line,1,black)
        screen.blit(label, (0, 20))

#       label = myfont.render("012345678901234567890",1,black)
#       screen.blit(label, (0, 50))     

        if GPIO.input(13):
            if lap_pressed == False:
                lap_pressed = True
                tick = 19
                while tick > 0:
                    lap_time[tick] = lap_time[tick-1]
                    tick = tick - 1
                lap_time[0] = str(race_count)
        else:
             lap_pressed = False 

        tick = 0
        while tick < 3:
            label = myfont.render(str(lap_time[tick]),1,black)
            x_coord = (tick*150)
            screen.blit(label, (x_coord,200 ))
            tick = tick + 1

        while tick < 6:
            label = myfont.render(str(lap_time[tick]),1,black)
            x_coord = ((tick-3)*150)
            screen.blit(label, (x_coord, 250))          
            tick = tick + 1

        while tick < 9:
            label = myfont.render(str(lap_time[tick]),1,black)
            x_coord = ((tick-6)*150)
            screen.blit(label, (x_coord, 300))
            tick = tick + 1

        red_light = False
        amber_light = False
        green_light = False     

        if race_count >= -300:
            race_string = "Five Minutes"

        if race_count >= -240:
            race_string = "Four Minutes"
            red_light = True

        if race_count >= -60:
            race_string = "One Minute"
            red_light = False
            amber_light= True

        if race_count >= 0:
            race_string ="Race Started"
            amber_light = False
            green_light = True

        if last_string <> race_string:
            last_string = race_string
            hooter_finish = current_time + hooter_length
        if current_time <= hooter_finish:
            GPIO.output(hooter_out, True)
        else:
            GPIO.output(hooter_out, False)

        GPIO.output(red_out, red_light)
        GPIO.output(amber_out, amber_light)
        GPIO.output(green_out, green_light)     



        label = myfont.render(race_string,1,black)
        screen.blit(label, (0,80))  

        pg.display.flip()

#       if GPIO.input(12) == False:
#           running = False     
    GPIO.output(16,False)
    GPIO.output(18,False)
    GPIO.output(22,False)
    GPIO.output(7,False)

#   for event in pg.event.get():
#       if event.type == pg.QUIT:
#           running = False

#   label = font.render("Some text!", 1, (255,255,0))
#   screen.blit(label, (100,100))
```

Any Advice on how i could add modes would be appreciated

Comment: What do you mean by 'modes'? Also, you should provide a [mcve] and explain what exactly doesn't work and how do you _want_ it to work. If that code works already and you're just asking how to implement another feature, I'm sorry, but this is the wrong site: we don't  write code for you from scratch.

Comment: I just wanted to know where to put the button input and if statement to swich modes, I was not asking people to write it for me